# Where do I find out which anonymous classes implement an interface in M3?

Tags: rascal

I am using Rascal to detect polymorphic types (with > 1 implementation) via the M3 model.
In JHotDraw 6 (http://www.jhotdraw.org/) there is an interface `org::jhotdraw::framework::ViewChangeListener` that is implemented only by anonymous classes, but the m3 model for JHotDraw does not seem to contain this information.

```
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
import lang::java::m3::TypeHierarchy;
jhd6 = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://jhotdraw60b1|);
vcl = |java+interface:///org/jhotdraw/framework/ViewChangeListener|;
invert(jhd6@implements)[vcl];
```

returns an empty set.

The anonymous class `|java+anonymousClass:///org/jhotdraw/standard/AbstractTool/createViewChangeListener()/$anonymous1|` can be found in the m3 model, but it is not recognized as implementing the ViewChangeListener interface.

Is there a reliable way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

M3 by itself does not have this information. The implements relation in the model contains only those pair which use the "implements" keyword in the source. For anonymous classes this is not the case.

This information is available in the AST. The newObject constructor below in the AST include the anonymous class in the Declaration class and the class/interface the anonymous class references can be obtained from Type \type.

`\newObject(Expression expr, Type \type, list[Expression] args, Declaration class)`

`\newObject(Type \type, list[Expression] args, Declaration class)`

Maybe including the referenced class in the @types relation of M3 would make sense. Currently if we look at the types relation, for the example you provided we get

`<|java+anonymousClass:///org/jhotdraw/standard/AbstractTool/createViewChangeListener()/$anonymous1|, |java+anonymousClass:///org/jhotdraw/standard/AbstractTool/createViewChangeListener()/$anonymous1|>`

maybe

`<|java+anonymousClass:///org/jhotdraw/standard/AbstractTool/createViewChangeListener()/$anonymous1|,|java+interface:///org/jhotdraw/framework/ViewChangeListener|>`

would make more sense. I will look into it.